# Цикл создания кнопок в android studio

Tags: java, android, циклы

Всем привет, помогите разобраться, на activity есть главная кнопка, нажатие на неё должно приводить к созданию дочерней кнопки, след нажатие на главную кнопку - ещё одна дочерняя кнопка, под уже созданной и так 10 раз. После 10 раза, нажатие на главную кнопку должно приводить к тому, что кнопки должны исчезать одна за одной по кругу. Не могу догнать как сделать цикл, появление/исчезновение кнопок через setVisibility(View.*VISIBLE/invisible*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public String arr[] = {String.valueOf(R.id.button1), String.valueOf(R.id.button2), String.valueOf(R.id.button3), String.valueOf(R.id.button4)};
public Boolean bool = true;
public int i = 0;
//
public void onClick(View view){
    View _view = findViewById(Integer.parseInt(arr[i]));
    if (bool){
        _view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        i++;
    } else {
        _view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        i--;
    }
    if (i == 4){
        i--;
        bool = false;
    } else if (i == -1){
        i++;
        bool = true;
    }
}
```

// я так сделал

Comment: большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Здесь не нужен цикл. Сделайте простой счётчик. При клике увеличивайте его на единицу, пока он не станет равный 10. Потом уменьшайте.

А кнопкам присвойте индекс от 1 до 10. Как только счётчик изменил своё значение, меняйте видимость кнопки с соответствующим индексом.

```
private boolean increment;
private int clickCount = 0;

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (clickCount == 0) {
            increment = true;
        } else if (clickCount == 10) {
            increment = false;
        }

        if (increment) {
            clickCount++;
        } else {
            clickCount--;
        }

        toggleButtonAtIndex(clickCount);
    }
});
```

Comment: Можно пример счетчика?

Comment: @mike Добавил пример